# How to pass raw complex object to MVC action?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Problem: Can't parse File object to JSON string, when doing that only null values are gotten, while trying to send complex type to MVC controller.

I tried adding it into FormData object and passing it to controller, however, passing List of them was not successful, because it would either return an empty array or just plain null

model:

```cs
public class UploadedDocument
    {

        public HttpPostedFile File { get; set;}
        public string DocumentId { get; set;}
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }

    }
```

controller:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("UploadFile")]
        public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<UploadedDocument> documents)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

upload function:

```
var _documents = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfFiles.length; i++) {

                    var document = {
                        "File": arrayOfFiles[i].file,
                        "DocumentId": arrayOfFiles[i].documentId,
                        "DocumentType": arrayOfFiles[i].documentName
                    };

                    _documents.push(document);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Home")",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {"documents":_documents}
                    });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try this in your ajax call: data: JSON.stringify({ _documents }),

Comment: @user1987392 You see, that's the problem, that JSON.stringify() cannot be used on File objects (can't remember why) and when I do it only returns and empty array

Comment: Replace this in your AJAX `data: JSON.stringify(_documents, null, 4)` and it will all work correctly

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I tried it, but controller received a null

Comment: In your Ajax Method try Add    contentType: false,
                        processData: false, to see if it will work.

Comment: i´m pretty sure you need to use FormData to get it to work

Comment: @SamuelAkosile also, returns a null

Comment: @johnSmith I will try again, even though when I tried before I got a null as well

Comment: @MartynasAntipenkovas let me post how I manage upload via ajax. Though i only upload a single file unlike yours that has to do with multiple files. You may be able to pick something out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I manage to handle single upload via ajax like below

**Input Element**

```
  <input type="file" name="customerpicture" id="customerpicture" />
```

**Formdata**

```
 function getFormData() {
        var data = new FormData();
        var files = $("#customerpicture").get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
            data.append("file", files[0]);
        }
        //data.append("Name", $("#name").val());

        return data;
    }
```

**Ajax Method**

```
$('#InsertCustomer').click(function () {
        debugger;
            var antiForgeryToken = $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val();
            var url = '@Url.Action("Add_Customer", "Customer")';

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": antiForgeryToken },
                    url: url,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: getFormData(),
                    success: function (res) {
                            $('#custinsertmodal').modal('hide');
                            $('#custinsertmodal').find("input,textarea,select")
                                .val('')
                                .end()
                                .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
                                .prop("checked", "")
                                .end();
                            bootbox.alert({ message: res.result });   
                    }
                });     
        });
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost, ValidateHeaderAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Add_Customer()
    {
        var errMsg = string.Empty;
        byte[] tmpImage;
        try
        {
            //Customer Image Processing
            var file = Request.Files.Get("file");

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //Image Saving to Folder
                UploadHelper.UploadFile(file);

                //Image Saving to Database
                tmpImage = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(tmpImage, 0, file.ContentLength);

                CustomerModel model = new CustomerModel
                {

                    Signature = tmpImage
                };
                _setupRepo.CreateSignatory(model);
                return Json(new { error = false, result = $"Customer was successfully created" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errMsg = ex.Message.ToString();
            return Json(new { error = true, result = errMsg }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: for some reason ```var file``` is set to null for me, even when I tailored it to my application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specifically use an ajax call to upload files: you need to use a FormData object. Files must be sent up as a single item within the FormData object and therefore cannot be passed to your ActionResult as part of a list.

Assuming you have a dynamic amount of file inputs on your page with custom fields the user can fill in, your code could look like the following:

HTML / Javascript:

```
<form id="File_Form">
    <input type="file" name="File_1" />
    <input type="text" name="DocumentName_File_1" value="doc1" />
    <input type="text" name="DocumentId_File_1" value="1" />

    <input type="file" name="File_2" />
    <input type="text" name="DocumentName_File_2" value="doc2" />
    <input type="text" name="DocumentId_File_2" value="2" />

    <button>Upload Files</button>
</form>

<script>
    $("#File_Form").submit(function() {
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false
        });

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles() {
    foreach (string fileName in Request.Files) {
        HttpPostedFileWrapper file = Request.Files[fileName];
        string documentName = Request.Form[$"DocumentName_{fileName}"]?.ToString();
        string documentId = Request.Form[$"DocumentId_{fileName}"]?.ToString();

        // Do things with your file here.
    }
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

It may not automatically serialize into your model object, but you can still obtain the result you want with clever naming of your form elements.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. 
   var _documents = [];

```
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfFiles.length; i++) {

                    var document = {
                        "File": arrayOfFiles[i].file,
                        "DocumentId": arrayOfFiles[i].documentId,
                        "DocumentType": arrayOfFiles[i].documentName
                    };

                    _documents.push(document);
                }

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("documents", documents);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Home")",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sadly, I have tried this before and it sends in an empty array/list